"Spacefactor in Vertical mode" error
In my Latex tempalte (pandoc: markdown -> latex -> pdf) I have the following code:
\begin{center}
    \vfill {\bf{\LARGE{ $class$ }}}
    \vfill {\bf{\LARGE{ \@title }}}
    \vfill{ {$if(abstract)$\begin{abstract}$abstract$\end{abstract}$endif$}}
    \vfill{ \bf{  } }
\end{center}

Which results in this error:
Error producing PDF.
! You can't use `\spacefactor' in vertical mode.
\@->\spacefactor
             \@m {}
l.360           \vfill {\bf{\LARGE{ \@

I know it is this code as when I change it to:
\begin{center}
    \vfill {\bf{\LARGE{ $class$ }}}
    %\vfill {\bf{\LARGE{ \@title }}}
    \vfill{ {$if(abstract)$\begin{abstract}$abstract$\end{abstract}$endif$}}
    \vfill{ \bf{  } }
\end{center}

it works.

Here is the full titlepage for context:
\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[height=2cm]{/template/figures/Logo.png}
    \end{minipage}

    \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
        \begin{flushright}
        School
        \end{flushright}
    \end{minipage}

    \begin{center}
        \vfill {\bf{\LARGE{ $class$ }}}
        \vfill {\bf{\LARGE{ \@title }}}
        \vfill{ {$if(abstract)$\begin{abstract}$abstract$\end{abstract}$endif$}}
        \vfill{ \bf{  } }
    \end{center}

    $if(lecturer)$
    \begin{tabbing}
        \hspace{5cm}\=\kill
        \textbf{Dozent(in)}\>$lecturer$\\
    \end{tabbing}
    $endif$
    
    \subsection*{Studierende(r):}
    \begin{tabbing}
        \hspace{5cm}\=\kill
        \textbf{Autor(en)}
        $for(author)$
            \>$author$$sep$,\\ 
        $endfor$\\
        \textbf{Wohnort, Datum:}\>Location, \@date
    \end{tabbing}

\end{titlepage}


Unrelated \bf does not take arguments and have been deprecated since 1993! \LARGE does not take arguments either.

Thanks for all your inputs, I am a markdown guy first, so I am in over my head when it comes to pure latex.

Commands with @ in their name can not be used in document (unless you allow them with \makeatletter). But you can use \UseName{@title} instead of \@title
